# microsoft dynamics webAPI listing purchase orders

Tags: axapta, dynamics-365-operations

How do you list purchase orders using the Microsoft Dynamics WebAPI?

Similarly, how do I list purchase orders with their line items using WebAPI?

I am having a real hard time finding decent and clear documentation on using WebAPI to find purchase orders, and especially purchase order line items, so any help would be appreciated.  I just need a good starting point.  Even some library would help, as I could look at what the library is doing and maybe try to mimic it.

Comment: you can try with Dataverse REST Builder https://github.com/GuidoPreite/DRB

Comment: Dataverse WebAPI does not seem to have purchase orders.  And the demo for this app does not have it either.  I want to know about getting purchase orders via the webAPI (or some other method that works from Linux).  Am I off base, is there no way to do it?

Comment: the tag you wrote is "dynamics-crm-webapi", which exact Dynamics 365 product you are using?

Comment: Our potential customer just said "Microsoft Dynamics".  We care about purchase orders, so whichever product offers that information is the product we can interface with.  Sorry for choosing wrong tag.  Was looking for webapi related to dynamics, and I guess I chose the wrong one.

Comment: There is no tag that perfectly fits me, it looks like.  Regardless, my original question clearly mentions purchase orders, and webapi, so hopefully that is enough for people to point me in the right direction.

Comment: Dynamics can refer to 3 products, Dynamics NAV (now called Business Central), Dynamics AX (now called Dynamics 365 F&O Finance&Operation), Dynamics CRM (now called Dynamics 365 CE Customer Engagement). So if your potential customer didn't tell you which of the 3 products he meant, how can we know? ask the customer exactly which application he is using and use the right tags

Comment: Dynamics 365 F&O (Dynamics AX)

Comment: tags updated, you can try to ask also here https://community.dynamics.com/ax/f/microsoft-dynamics-ax-forum

Comment: Take a look at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/fin-ops-core/dev-itpro/data-entities/odata. The potential customer or their Microsoft partner should be able to provide you with the purchase order OData endpoints.